# How to import and call 'main' functions from different files

Tags: python

I have bunch of python script files that i've created, and running them one by one. how can call these script files and run methods one by one from a different script file. I need little help as method in each file is named main() and i'm not sure how to import and call this method by the same name.

file1.py

```
import sys

def main():
   #do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

file2.py

```
import sys

def main():
   #do something else

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: `import file2`; `file2.main()` ?

Comment: The name `main` is not important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following syntax will work for you:

```
from file1 import main as main1
from file2 import main as main2
...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply import them as modules, and call the `main()` function for each

```
import file1, file2
file1.main()
file2.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to import `main` from file1.py into file2.py, you can do `from file1 import main as main1` or some other name. This way, you give an alias to the function name. Alternatively, `import file1` and then call `file1.main()`